# Onsen UI Render All Tabs On Display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phonegap-plugins, onsen-ui

I am using [onsen-ui](/questions/tagged/onsen-ui) [Tab Bar](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-tabbar.html) component, When trying to access HTML element of any tab other than the displayed one before rendering it, I always get **undefined**.

I have made this workaround method which is called after displaying the tab bar on the screen:

```
var test = function () {
    var tabbar = $scope.tabbar;
    if (typeof tabbar != 'undefined') {
        var len = tabbar._tabItems.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var tabItem = tabbar._tabItems[i];
            tabItem.setActive(true);
            tabItem.setActive(false);
        }
        tabbar._tabItems[len - 1].setActive(true);
    };
};
```

But after executing this method the selected tab is displayed empty, I must click its tab again to show its content.

Any help?

Comment: `setActive()` method is not public/documented and it doesn't even receive parameters, so passing `true` or `false` won't change much. And in any case it will just change the CSS of the tab itself, not the content of the page. If you want to load pages you have to use `tabbar.setActiveTab(index, options)`.